# Why does the font of my UITextField change when editing?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

My UITextField's font gets lighter when it is being edited, and bolder whenever editing finishes. These images should illustrate the problem:

[image: Editing]
[image: Not Editing]

Can anyone explain why this is, and how to stop it?

This is all the code I've got for it - first my UITextField subclass (which is just there to add margins):

```
@interface RLTextField : UITextField {    
}
@end

@implementation RLTextField

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect editingRect = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x+35, bounds.origin.y-5, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
    return editingRect;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect editingRect = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x+35, bounds.origin.y-5, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
    return editingRect;
}
@end
```

And then where it's actually added in my viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    CGRect noteTitleTextFrame  = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, 
                                            self.view.bounds.origin.y+10, 
                                            self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                                            44);
    RLTextField *textField = [[RLTextField alloc] initWithFrame:noteTitleTextFrame];
    self.nameTextField = textField; [textField release];
    self.nameTextField.delegate = self;
    self.nameTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;    
    self.nameTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
    self.nameTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:21];
    [self.view addSubview:self.nameTextField]; 
}
```

Comment: may i know what is mean by RLTextField?

Comment: It's just my subclass of UITextField - I've added the @interface above to make that clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

checked your code.... and there only one word for that **WTF**....!
I don't know what's wrong with that but there is a solution for that and it's

```
self.nameTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier New" size:21];
```

just change the font name. This will work.. cheers :)
By the way you probably found a bug or may be not that's why apple has added "Courier New". 
I don't know...

Comment: Ha, I thought the "WTF" was referring to my coding quality for a moment there! Anyway, just as you suggested, changing the font worked. Thanks!

Comment: I am having same issue but don't know why this is happening. I am using Avenir Next font.

Comment: @S.J I really don't have any idea why this was happening, my be use other font or just file a bug @ https://bugreport.apple.com/